# What is the capacity of Linux Mint OS?

Tags: linux-mint

How large is the Linux Mint OS download?

I am considering downloading it. When I know how much volume it has I can figure out how long it take to download. Any current version of Mint is OK.

Comment: You mean how large its disk usage is?

Comment: yes your are correct.

Comment: @phk you are correct. i assume u are not notified on my reply sin i didnt mention your name front of the message.

Answer (score 2):

The capacity of Linux Mint 18 Sarah Cinnamon 64-bit is 1.7 Gb and 32-bit is 1.5 Gb.
Here is the link to download:

https://www.linuxmint.com/release.php?id=27